# MySQL not allowing text columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, full-text-search, mysql-workbench, character-set

I'm using MySQL 5.5.27. I currently have a BLOB column, that I want to convert to text to allow fulltext searching. The `ALTER TABLE` command to create a text column is successful, but the `ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX index (column ASC)` to create a fulltext index returns an error, saying I cannot create a fulltext index on that column.

When I go back and look at the specs for the table, it appears as BLOB, instead of text.

I'm using MySQLWorkbench, but I've generally been running the scripts by hand, instead of using the wizard.

I have tried setting a character encoding for the entire schema (none existed before) thinking that this would be needed for text columns, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
ALTER TABLE ADD FULLTEXT INDEX index (column ASC);
```

sounds like it does not make sense.

What does FULLTEXT indexing a column in ascending order mean?

You should run it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD FULLTEXT INDEX index (column);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: It accepts the command, but returns the same error: "Column 'column' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index"

I'm thinking the problem has to do with the column being of "BLOB" type, but I can't alter it to TEXT. I run `ALTER TABLE table CHANGE COLUMN column TEXT` , but `DESCRIBE` still tells me `column` is of type BLOB..

Comment: Please post the SHOW CREATE TABLE of the table into your question. I will show you how.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ronaldo:
I ran `SHOW CREATE TABLE` I see that my charset is set to binary. I ran `ALTER TABLE table charset = utf8` Now all works.

Comment: Did my answer help at all ???

Comment: @JoshuaKast if the answer helped, a good way to show it is clicking the checkmark below the vote count.  This shows to Ronaldo and everyone else that this solved your issue.